# ownCloud "Downgrading not supported" after apt-get upgrade

Tags: upgrade, owncloud

I am running an ownCloud installation on Raspbian on an RPi2 and I just ran:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now I get the following message when I try to go to my ownCloud-site in the browser:

> Downgrading is not supported and is likely to cause unpredictable
>   issues (from 8.2.2.2 to 8.1.5.2)

I did not make any changes and definitely didn't do any downgrade (consciously). The files are stored on an external HDD and seem to be unaffected. I wasn't really actively using my cloud storage yet (fortunately), so I wouldn't really mind if the data I had put there was lost, but I'd like to keep the other data stored on the HDD (outside the ownCloud folder) if possible. What would you suggest as the best way forward? I thought about just removing ownCloud via apt-get purge - or would that be unsave or leave some junk on my system (I'd maybe have to delete the database manually)? And how can I avoid this problem in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to connect to the [official repository](https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/owncloud/)

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_14.04/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key

sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! I'll add that I had to manually put it our of maintenance mode afterwards by setting 'maintenance' to false in /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php (hoping that was the correct way to do it)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, but only partly. After the upgrade, Owncloud had apparently skipped a version and I had to downgrade, then update again through the skipped version as described [here](https://central.owncloud.org/t/updates-between-multiple-major-versions-and-downgrades-are-unsupported/815)

Answer (score 4):

same problem here - find out that i have old owncloud http in source list:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/Debian_7.0/

new one is (check official page)
http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Debian_7.0/

change it, run upgrade again and manually disable maintenance mode (in /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php)

Comment: The official documentation page is this: https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/owncloud/

Comment: Follow the above link provided by @William for the complete command list, you may need to add a new package (was my case on debian 7).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me... Just this morning...
I think it's necessary to download current release from OwnCloud and re-install starting from it.
But before: I'll check if is possible to add OwnCloud as source of apt package, so a new apt-get update / apt-get upgrade will solve the problem and avoid future similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://www.der-webcode.de/owncloud-manuelles-updateupgrade-von-owncloud/. Works fine for me. Don't forget to set Maintaince to false in your config.php.

Torsten

Comment: linked article is in german, please copy here revelant part translated to english.

Answer (score 0):

thank you fixed if still have problems try this

Stop the upgrade process this way:
cd /var/www/owncloud/
sudo -u www-data php occ maintenance:mode --off
And start the manual process:
sudo -u www-data php occ upgrade
If this does not work properly, try the repair function:
sudo -u www-data php occ maintenance:repair